# Glassfish 4, Eclipse IDE 2019-03 - CustomRealm: AppservPasswordLoginModule cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: eclipse, glassfish-4

I would like to implement a Custom Realm by overriding the security classes but I'm getting an error:
*AppservPasswordLoginModule cannot be resolved to a type
The import com.sun.appserv cannot be resolved*

I followed the steps from this tutorial: https://computingat40s.wordpress.com/how-to-create-a-custom-realm-in-glassfish-3-1-2-2/

What I did:

1. I created a new java project
2. Added a new lib folder to my project.
3. Copied the security.jar(also tried with security-ee.jar) from $glassfish-installation-folder\glassfish\modules to lib folder
4. I added this line to my .classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/security.jar" />
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I also tried to add the jar to build path using Eclipse GUI
**NOTES:** I'm not using MAVEN, I also tried to clean the project as it was mentioned in other answers

After making this steps Eclipse throws me an arror when I want to extend MyCustomModule with AppservPasswordLoginModule:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9afOm.png)

Comment: Eclipse IDE 2019-03 is almost four years and 15 releases behind. Please upgrade. You added `security.jar` to your _Java Build Path_, but not `security-ee.jar`. Did you do that intentionally? Under the _Referenced Libraries_ node, you can expand the JARs to see what they contain.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser! I also tried adding security-ee.jar to java build path but it didn't worked! I also tried to search the class in the two mentioned JARs but I didn't find the class that I need.

Comment: Well does that class exist in Glassfish 4? The document you reference is for Glassfish 3

Comment: Yes I searched in the documentation and the  they are referring to this class: https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/4.0/application-development-guide.pdf  Adding all the jars in a new Library solved the issue

Comment: Does this question involve MongoDB Realm, the database, and the tag indicates? If so, what's the tie-in?

Comment: Sorry Jay! It was my first question I made a mistake. I removed  the realm tag! Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE!

I found the JAR that must be added to JAVA build path: **glassfish-ee-api.jar**

---

I solved the problem by creating a new library where I copied all the JARS from $glassfish-installation-folder\glassfish\modules
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqiGz.png)